# selecting a specific cluster and highlighting data in r

Tags: r

I've tried k-means(pamk) to cluster iris data and have got 3 clusters.

Q1:And I'd like to know how to select a specific cluster with all its related information such as sepal.length et ac.

Q2: how to speficy a set of data in clustering plot(I want to highlight a set of data in plot)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Seems the the clustering object is S3, so treat it like a list with `names(cluster)` and work from there. I only get two clusters, but I probably doing things differently.

```
library(fpc)

# Run the cluster
clus <- pamk(iris[,1:4])

# Extract the cluster info (the clus object is in efect, a list of lists)
# This component is a vector of cluster definitions
cluster <- clus$pamobject$clustering

# Those associated with the first cluster
iris[cluster == 1, ]

# The segregation of Species by cluster
sapply(split(iris$Species, f = cluster), table)
```